# Use current Identity user ID with AutoMapper in .NET 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, automapper

I would like to know how I can access the current user ID inside AutoMapper when using Identity Framework.

```cs
{
    public class MovieDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool HasLiked { get; set; } // indicates if the current has liked the movie
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to access `ClaimsPrincipal` from inside AutoMapper profile, for example:

```cs
CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.HasLiked, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
               src.UserLike.Any(ul => 
               ul.UserId == User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value));
```

Is it possible to achieve that with AutoMapper?

If that is not possible or not indicated, what should I do perform such query in my repository in a reusable way?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: Thank you @LucianBargaoanu, that worked. I'm new to the whole C# and .Net world, so I didn't noticed this part of the documentation related to parameterization. After a few tries, I figured out how it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @LucianBargaoanu comment, I was able to figure out how to do this properly, so I've decided to answer to help others starting with .Net:

Create a `currentUserId` to hold the user id.

```cs
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        string currentUserId = null;

        CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.HasLiked, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
                    src.UserLikes.Any(ul => ul.UserId == currentUserId)));
    }
}
```

When projecting using AutoMapper, pass `currentUserId` as a parameter:

```cs
public async Task<MovieDto> GetMoviesdAsync(string userId)
{
    return await _context.Movies
        .ProjectTo<MovieDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider, new { currentUserId = userId })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

And, this is how I get the UserId in the Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieDto>>> GetMovies()
{
    var userId = User.GetUserId();
    return Ok(await _unitOfWork.AuctionRepository.GetMoviesdAsync(userId));
}
```

This is the extensions method that I use to get the UserId:

```cs
public static class ClaimsPrincipleExtension
{
    public static string GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    }
}
```